# how to sort 2d linked list array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have got a 2d list array to which I am adding characters in a loop like below. I need to be able to sort in lexiographical order each sub container of of the 2d array. Unfortunately, Collections.sort(list) does not work in this case.

```
  List<Character>[][] list = new LinkedList[n][n];


  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
  {
     for (int m = 0; m < 1; m++)
     {
                // Here is the problem
        list[j][m].add(new Character('b'));

        // sort the array and continue
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Collections.sort(list)` wont work because `list` is an 2D array, do `Collections.sort(list[j][m])` while every iteration. This will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare a list of a lists, I suggest you to use the [ColumnComparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/column-comparator/) class: